# Negative timestamp -- does it makes sense in PHP?

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

According to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php), PHP uses the Unix Epoch (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970) to generate its timestamps.

Given this definition, I believe that it is reasonable to work with negative timestamps, when the target date is before the Unix Epoch. But, since time is a complicated matter in programming, I want to know if there is any caveat in using negative timestamps in PHP.

Comment: unix timestamps START at jan 1/1970, but since they're signed 32bit ints in "classic" unix, they can represent a range of roughly 1902 -> 2038.

Comment: Y2K was a piece of cake! What I'm really concerned about is Y2038 :|

Comment: @VictorKilo, don't worry! Everything we use today probably will be obsolete by then ;)

Comment: @Metalcoder - That's what everyone has been banking on... haha

Comment: By that time, we may use 64 bit timestamps. I hope. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, you're absolutely right. Negative numbers is just the amount of seconds before the Unix Epoch.

Comment: When you say _no_, do you mean _No problem_?

Comment: Indeed, no problem, no caveat. :)